# Xamarin Forms OnConfigurationChanged - System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null Parameter name: enumerable

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm working on my first Xamarin Forms application. I've run into an issue that I cannot figure out how to debug. There's a null value in the theme. But there aren't a lot of indicators as to what may be missing. If I catch this exception and ignore it, there doesn't seem to be any issue with the app execution.

When I change the orientation of the phone, I get this exception:

```
{System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: enumerable
  at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.EnumerableExtensions.IndexOf[T] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] enumerable, T item) [0x00003] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\EnumerableExtensions.cs:79 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Application.OnRequestedThemeChanged (Xamarin.Forms.AppThemeChangedEventArgs args) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Application.cs:172 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.OnConfigurationChanged (Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig) [0x0001e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:90 
  at App1.Droid.MainActivity.OnConfigurationChanged (Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig) [0x00002] in C:\source\repos\App1\App1\App1.Android\MainActivity.cs:30 }
```

I see it comes from the internal Forms code. Any idea what it is trying to enumerate over?

The comment asks for the code at line MainActivity.cs:30 
The code at line 30 is `base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);`

The point is that the exception happens in the internal Xamarin.Forms code and I have no idea what the enumeration is supposed to represent.

```
  public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
        {
            string m = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Some code would be useful for example line `App1\App1\App1.Android\MainActivity.cs:30`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and rolling Xamarin.Forms back to version 4.6.0.726 fixed it.

I have submitted a bug report on Xamarin.Forms Github https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10733